# How would I go about not allowing a user to login if Google ReCaptcha doesn't pass?

Tags: php, recaptcha

To begin with, I'm having difficulties tying the Google ReCaptcha into my login form. Just for some background information, this is all running on a live webserver with an SSL Certificate, I've got the correct site and secret keys and all that jazz.

Here's my login form:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

<br />
<p>Please log in to your account below:</p>

<form action="index.php" method="post" target="_self">
    <b>User Name:</b><br>
    <input type="text" size="20" name="userid"><br />
<br />
    <b>Password:</b><br>
    <input type="password" size="20" name="password"><br />
<br />

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="_MY PUBLIC SITE KEY_"></div>
<br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    <input type="hidden" value="validate" name="content">
</form>
```

And my script to validate:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $userid = $_POST["userid"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $secretkey = "_MY SECRET KEY_";
    $responsekey = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $useripaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretkey}&response={$responsekey}&remoteip={$useripaddress}";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $response;
}

require_once("scripts/thecrab.php");

$userid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userid']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT userid from users where userid = ? and password = PASSWORD(?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$userid, $password]);

if (!$stmt->rowCount() & $response->success == 0) {
    echo "<h2>Sorry, your user account was not validated.</h2><br>\n";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php?content=login\">Try again</a><br>\n";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Return to Home</a>\n";
} else {
    $_SESSION['valid_recipe_user'] = $userid;
    echo "<h2>Log In Successful</h2><br>\n";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php\"><img src=\"images/image-11.png\"></a>\n";
}
?>
```

So here's the few issues that I am having. If you notice, at the top of my page that validates the information, I've got
    echo $response;
That's in there strictly for testing purposes, so that I can see if the ReCaptcha comes back as true or false, but even when filling out the ReCaptcha, it always comes back as false, no matter what the security setting is set to on my Google site. I added pre tags around the validation so that it could spit back the results in an easier form to read and I'm greeted with this even when I fill out the Captcha:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error-codes": [
        "missing-input-response"
    ]
}
```

Now, since I'm stuck with an eternal "false", I decided to give the if statement a shot and implement in, if the success is false (ie. 0) then don't login, else login. Pretty simple, and you can see that at the bottom of my validation page in the if statement:

```
if (!$stmt->rowCount() & $response->success == 0)
```

So far so good, I FTP it up to the server, refresh and give it a go. But this time I get an error, and it states that the variable $response is undefined. Well I defined the variable at the top of the validation page where I said:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) // Checks to see if the form was submitted
```

And it was submitted as I hit the Login button that has name="submit", so it see's that submit is set with the value of login, so it executes what follows the if (you know how PHP works), and at the bottom is where it defines $response. As far as I know, with PHP, it doesn't matter which block the variable is defined in, as long as it gets executed then it can be used anywhere.

So all in all, the issues I'm having is:

1. ReCaptcha always evaluates to False
2. Error thrown stating $response is undefined despite it being defined
3. Ties in with #2, since variable is undefined, it can't execute the if statement.

I've tried almost everything in my skillset.

Comment: Can I see where are you validating your recaptcha ? like if ($response->is_valid) {//code}

Comment: @Brian which version of recaptcha are you using? 2.0 the latest one ?

Comment: @SaadSuri Yes it is at the bottom of the validate form.

    if (!$stmt->rowCount() & $response->success == 0)

$stmt is comparing my $userid and $password to the database, so if that comes back false and my response->success comes back as false/0, it'll execute what's below which redirects back to the login. But the recaptcha is always evaluating to false.

EDIT: Yes, I am using v2.0

Comment: Did you check the $response->success before using it in condition to see what's in it ?

Comment: @SaadSuri yes, at the top of my validation page I store the "g-recaptcha-reponse" into $responsekey, from there I send it off to Google attached to the URL and store the contents of $url into $reponse, I then echo $response and I'm greeted with "success" - false,


 I stated all of this in my post.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't read it. Just a last thing which version of recaptcha are you using ?

Comment: @SaadSuri Version 2.0, the regular, NOT the insivible captcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check again the parameters you're passing to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. 
The response parameter must be responSe and not respone.

This causes the error returned by the server - "missing-input-response" means you're not passing the "g-recaptcha-response" parameter

Now that the response is working:

1. file_get_contents will return a string, containing a JSON response. If you want to access the success value in the JSON the way you're accessing here

   ```
   if (!$stmt->rowCount() & $response->success == 0) {
   ```

   then you have to first use `json_decode` to create an object out of the string.
2. the if logic in that same row is using a bitwise AND operator as you're using a single ampersand & instead of &&
3. the logic itself - currently if no user account exists AND the recaptcha failed then there will be error, otherwise it is valid. The problem is that if there is no user but recaptcha is OK then the user is valid and if the user is ok and recaptcha failed then the user is still valid. So I'm guessing you meant to use OR instead of AND:

   ```
   if (!$stmt->rowCount() || $response->success == 0) {
   ```

Comment: WOW! It's always a simple mistake that throws everything off! Thank you so much.

Now that I'm getting a response, it comes back properly with the success as true and the timestamp along with the hostname. Sweet, now I'm stuggling on getting the if/else statement to work out properly. Is the way I currently have it setup not correct?